# Costum references (from TU Delft dissertation template) to work with parts

Tags: tikz-pgf, cross-referencing, chapters, parts

I am currently working on modifying the TU Delft (TUD) dissertation template ([found here](https://intranet.tudelft.nl/services/communicatie/handleidingen/handleiding-huisstijl/downloads/)) to meet my needs. Instead of just chapters I will have parts as well. The referencing of the TUD template assumes it is a section within a chapter, however, I would like it to be a chapter (without a number) within a part.

The problem I am facing is the following:

```
\chapter{References}
\begingroup
%\renewcommand{\chapter}[2]{}
\renewcommand{\section}[2]{} 
% To remove the section title 
% that \references automatically makes
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\references{bibliography/dispReferences}
\endgroup
```

This give me the chapter '# Reference' and the title name will be on the upper right/left corner of the pages in that chapter. However, removing the chapter number by using

```
\chapter*{References}
```

will also remove the chapter title from the upper right/left of the pages in that chapter and replaces it with the chapter title of the previous chapter.

The corresponding \references part in the .cls file is listed below

```
%% Create an unnumbered reference section.
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand*\bibname{\color{title}References}}
\newcommand*\references[1]{%
\bibliographystyle{dissertation}%
\bibliography{#1}%
}
```

In addition to all this, the TUD template makes a small thumb print of the chapter number on the pages of each chapter. When using the code above (thus chapter with numbering) the references chapter number is not printed accordingly. When having a references chapter number it jumps to '0' while it should be for example '5'.

The creation of these thump prints is listed below

```
%% The lthumb command prints the current chapter number in a thumb index on the
%% left (even) page.
\newcommand*\lthumb{%
\ifthumb%
   \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
   \coordinate (top margin) at (0pt,1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep);
   \coordinate (left margin) at (1in+\evensidemargin,0pt);
%% Calculate the corners of the thumb index based on the current
%% chapter number.
 \coordinate (top left) at ($(current page.north west)-(top margin)-(0pt,\value{chapter}\thumbvspace-\thumbvspace)$);
 \coordinate (bottom right) at ($(top left)+(left margin)-(\thumbhspace,\thumbheight)$);
 %% Shift the left edge to prevent the rounded corner from showing.
 \coordinate (top left) at ($(top left)-(\thumbedge,0pt)$);
 %% Draw the thumb index.
 \fill[fill=thumb,rounded corners=\thumbedge](top left) rectangle (bottom right);
 %% Print the chapter number at the center right in the thumb index.
 \coordinate (center right) at ($(bottom right)+(0pt,0.5\thumbheight)$);
 \node at (center right)[anchor=east,inner sep=2\thumbedge]{
 \titlefont\bfseries\color{usc-black}
 \fontsize{0.75\thumbheight}{0.75\thumbheight}\selectfont
 \thechapter
 };
 \end{tikzpicture}%
 \fi%
 }
```

I have quite some time on this issue, therefore all the help is appreciated!

Comment: As usual: Such fragments are not useful for people willing to help you

Comment: Do you recommend deleting those sections? How would you formulate the question, cause I did find it hard to work what I meant in a clear and concise manner.

Comment: Give us a short, **compilable** code, resulting in the problem you have.  For example add a screenshot of one page of the resulting pdf and mark the problem you have ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a modern tool like `biblatex` i don't even see any of the reported problems. For a lack of a minimal working example, i cannot reproduce any of the issues and understand none of the statements made.

Following works perfectly. Unnumbered chapters that hold the bibliography for a part.

[image: texsxTUDelftBiblatex]

```
\RequirePackage{scrlfile}
\PreventPackageFromLoading{natbib}

\documentclass[whitelogo]{tudelft-report}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage{changes}
\begin{document}

%% Use Roman numerals for the page numbers of the title pages and table of
%% contents.
\frontmatter

%% Uncomment following 19 lines for a cover with a picture on the lower half only
%\title[tudelft-white]{Title}
%\subtitle[tudelft-cyan]{Optional subtitle}
%\author[tudelft-white]{J.\ Random Author}
%\affiliation{Technische Universiteit Delft}
%\coverimage{cover.jpg}
%\titleoffsetx{10cm}
%\titleoffsety{10cm}
%\afiloffsetx{1cm}
%\afiloffsety{18cm}
%\covertext[tudelft-white]{
%    \textbf{Cover Text} \\
%    possibly \\
%    spanning 
%    multiple 
%    lines
%    \vfill
%    ISBN 000-00-0000-000-0
%}
%\makecover

%% Uncomment following 16 lines for a cover with a picture on the lower half only
\title[tudelft-white]{The amazing journey of Walter Wombat in the
Land of Candy Sticks}
\subtitle[tudelft-black]{Optional subtitle}
\author[tudelft-white]{J.\ Random Author}
\affiliation{Technische Universiteit Delft}
\coverimage{tank.jpg}
\covertext[tudelft-white]{
    \textbf{Cover Text} \\
    possibly \\
    spanning 
    multiple 
    lines
    \vfill
    ISBN 000-00-0000-000-0
}
\setpagecolor{tudelft-cyan}
\makecover[split]


%% Include an optional title page.
\input{title}

\input{preface}

\tableofcontents

%% Use Arabic numerals for the page numbers of the chapters.
\mainmatter

\newrefsection
\part{I am a Wombat}
\chapter{A Wombat?}
No, i am just making fun, i am a
penguin.\cite{aristotle:physics,companion,westfahl:space}

\printbibliography
\newrefsection
\part{I am not a Walrus}
\chapter{Well, that is obvious}
Soy un peng\"uino.\cite{ctan,doody}
\printbibliography

%% Use letters for the chapter numbers of the appendices.
\appendix

%\input{appendix-a}


\end{document}
```

---

[image: tudelftDissertation]

```
\RequirePackage{scrlfile}
\PreventPackageFromLoading{natbib,chapterbib}
\documentclass{dissertation}

%% Turn off page numbering for the propositions and make the margins on both
%% sides equal and symmetrical.
\geometry{twoside=false}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage[style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}

%% Specify the title and author of the thesis. This information will be used on
%% both the English and Dutch side and in the metadata of the final PDF.
\title[Optional Subtitle]{Title}
\author{Albert}{Einstein}

\begin{center}

{\Large\titlefont\bfseries Propositions}

\bigskip

accompanying the dissertation

\bigskip

%% Print the title.
{\makeatletter
\titlestyle\bfseries\large\@title
\makeatother}

%% Print the optional subtitle.
{\makeatletter
\ifx\@subtitle\undefined\else
    \titlefont\titleshape\@subtitle
\fi
\makeatother}

\bigskip

by

\bigskip

%% Print the full name of the author.
\makeatletter
{\large\titlefont\bfseries\@firstname\ {\titleshape\@lastname}}
\makeatother

\end{center}



\bigskip
\bigskip

%% Apart from the name and title of the supervisor, the following text is
%% dictated by the promotieregelement.
\begin{center}
These propositions are regarded as opposable and defendable, and have been approved as such by the promotor prof.\ dr.\ A.\ Kleiner.
\end{center}

\clearpage
{\selectlanguage{dutch}

\begin{center}

{\Large\titlefont\bfseries Stellingen}

\bigskip

behorende bij het proefschrift

\bigskip

%% Print the title.
{\makeatletter
\titlestyle\bfseries\large\@title
\makeatother}

%% Print the optional subtitle.
{\makeatletter
\ifx\@subtitle\undefined\else
    \titlefont\titleshape\@subtitle
\fi
\makeatother}

\bigskip

door

\bigskip

%% Print the full name of the author.
\makeatletter
{\large\titlefont\bfseries\@firstname\ {\titleshape\@lastname}}
\makeatother

\end{center}


\newrefsection
\part{I am a Wombat}
\chapter{A Wombat?}
No, i am just making fun, i am a
penguin.\cite{aristotle:physics,companion,westfahl:space}

\printbibliography
\newrefsection
\part{I am not a Walrus}
\chapter{Well, that is obvious}
Soy un peng\"uino.\cite{ctan,doody}
\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks this helped as well. I have figured out what caused the problem. For some reason I have to use \cleardoublepage before each \part{}. Else it saw the chapter before the part as chapter 0 of the next part.

Comment: I tried to implement the method you discussed (using the biblatex and \ printbibliography), however no references are printed. It doesn't produce any errors/warning though. I use it as such: \chapter{References}
\printbibliography

Comment: You don't need any `\chapter` commands. What you need, is to set up your [editor to use biber](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/37907). I don't know how strict your rules are, but if they are strict, better use the provided bibliography  styles instead of switching to the new system shown in the answer.